# xpage - sessionID and DomAuthsessId

Tags: xpages

The domauthsessid cookie is created when a person logs on to domino server. I have also seen a cookie for sessionID when dealing with xpages. Is sessionID specific to xpages? How is this sessionID used by xpages?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021314:

> Q. Sometimes when XPage is submitted it adds SessionID to the URL and
> some JavaScript stops working. What's that SessionID?
>
> A. This is due to the way HTTP is working. HTTP is stateless so the
> browser must pass an ID to the server in order to keep a session open
> on the server. There are two ways for passing this ID.
>
> 1 - Passing the ID as part of the URL
>
> 2 - Passing the ID as part of the cookie from the browser
>
> The second way is the preferred way. But for the first page the XPages
> engine doesn't know if the browser that is connecting to the page is
> supporting cookies or not, so it tries first by passing an ID and a
> cookie. And on the second request it looks for the cookie, and if the
> cookie is there it removes the ID from the URL. So if you look at all
> the application servers they are all working like that. Now there is a
> property in XPages that says 'assume that the client has cookie', and
> in these cases do not use a session ID at all. So that would break
> some browsers that do not support having cookies enabled.

The sessionID URL parameter is not used with Lotus Domino 8.5.3 - only with 8.5.2 and older.

Comment: I am using 8.5.3 domino server with UP1. I see the sessionID cookie being set but I do not see it as part of URL.

Comment: Ah, you meant the sessionID cookie - and not the sessionID URL parameter. My mistake. As you can see from my answer, the sessionID cookie is used to maintain a session with the server.

Comment: I see the SessionID in the URL generated by an 8.5.3 server, Google is full of them (and has problems indexing the site). I suppose the SessionID is sent to GoogleBot.

Comment: "Now there is a property in XPages..." would be nice to tell what parameter it is or use link to documentation. +1 anyway, helped

Answer (score 1):

Create a Xpage as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    rendered="false"
>
    <xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:

var externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var request = externalContext.getRequest();
var response = externalContext.getResponse();
var currentContext = com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent();
var session = request.getSession(false);
var sessionId = session.getId();
// flush the cookies and invalidate the HTTP session...
for(var cookie in request.getCookies()){
    cookie.setValue("");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
session.invalidate();
// now nuke the XSP session from RAM, then jump to logout...
currentContext.getModule().removeSession(sessionId);
externalContext.redirect("?logout");
}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
</xp:view>
```

and then create a link or Page Link to point to the above Xpage…

This will log you out and remove ALL cookies.

DISCLAIMER: code found on the net (kudos to that person) and this will **not** work for client certificate authenticated servers…

Why paste this answer so late in the discussion? Because I've looked for the answer and none of the above is working so for future references…

Answer (score 0):

The sessionID cookie is used by XPages so that the server knows which session it dealing with so when you run some code like sessionScope.get(param) it knows which user's sessionScope to look at.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, a session represented with sessionId should not be confused with session-based authentication.

domauthsessid cookie is used in single-server authentication. If you are using multi-server authentication, LtpaToken will be used for that purpose. This cookies persist your authentication session.

XPages session will be preserved when you login, logout or even login with a different user. An XPages session will only be deleted after a specific idle time whereas authentication session is deleted when you logged out.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie manages the browser session for the server. If you do a ?logout, the sessionScope variables are not removed. You can use SSJS to clear the sessionScope map and logout, but that will only clear the map for the current NSF. If you remove the sessionID cookie, the XPages session is removed and all sessionScope variables for the whole server are removed. I added an snippet to the xSnippets OpenNTF site that does the logout and remove sessionID cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Mikael Andersson Wigander shows us a nice solution how to logout from a Domino server. However, the ?logout parameter in the URL isn't always working.

We found out that the logout page from Mikael only logged out a user in the first attempt. The browser then caches this logout page and prevents the user from logging out the next attempt.

The following change of Mikael's solution will tackle this problem:

```
var appUrl = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath();
var url =  appUrl +"?Logout&t=" + new Date().getTime() + "&redirectto=" + appUrl ;  
facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(url);
```

Call the Xpage using a parameter also containing the time in milliseconds:

```
<xe:this.href><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Logout.xsp?" + new Date().getTime();}]]></xe:this.href>
```

Now the user will be able to log out every attempt.